# Get indexes on postgres table using Laravel with Schema

Tags: laravel, postgresql

in Larave, when using MySQL, I can run this to get the indexes on a table:

```
$schemaManager = Schema::getConnection('my_connection')->getDoctrineSchemaManager();
$indexesFound  = $schemaManager->listTableIndexes('my_table');

print_r($indexesFound);
```

What is the corresponding way to do this in Laravel for a postgresql table? This command always returns an empty array, even though there are definitely indexes on my table.

Comment: How exactly did you verify that *there are definitely indexes on my table*?

Comment: your `$schemaManager` goes to `Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\MySQLSchemaManager ` or `PostgreSQLSchemaManager`? is your `'my_table'` correct?